# How can I get the feature vector (the N-1 layer's output before softmax) of input image from deep model?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, cntk

How can I get the feature vector (the N-1 layer's output before softmax) of an input image from deep model? I am using Microsoft's CNTK deep learning toolkit.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example that you may want to try out:
https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/tree/master/Examples/Image/FeatureExtraction